# python getopt error : "option --ip not recognized" from ipykernel_launcher

Tags: python, getopt

When I am running my python in vs code with ipython, I get error:

`option --ip not recognized`

it seems run with some default options, but impacts to my getopt function with bellow code:

```
#%%
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hs:v:m",["symbol=","vendor="])
for o, a in opts:
    if o == "-s":
        sym = a
    elif o == "-v":
        data_vendor = a
    elif o == "-m":
        massive_testing = True
    else:
        pass
```

I tried my debug code:

```
#%%
print(sys.argv)
```

I get bellow:

['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py', '--ip=127.0.0.1', '--stdin=9028', '--control=9026', '--hb=9025', '--Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256"', '--Session.key=b"a6676a2b-4cfa-4056-a571-5b5c95b0f3f1"', '--shell=9027', '--transport="tcp"', '--iopub=9029', '--f=/tmp/tmp-477906pu3LAf814T5H.json']

I don't want parse these system options, it there anyway work round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes, you can opt those out if you know your needed options beforehand

**NOTE**: I am using **4 spaces as indentation** here , python might give you error with invalid indentation

for those whose are in hurry , you can copy this codes as template and
without many comment

```
toptions = [] #add short options
long_options = []  #add long options  
unrecognisedlist = []  #for recognised options
recognised = []  #for unrecognised optoins
for arg in sys.argv[1:] :recognised.append(arg) if arg.strip('--') in long_options else unrecognisedlist.append(arg)

try:
    arguments, values = getopt.getopt(recognised, toptions, long_options)`
           #<your codes with arguments and values>
except Exceptions as e:
     print(e)
```

**As an Example** Try this,

```
 #adding needed option to a list for easiness , you can omit '='
 # I have added it like ,
 # long_options =["help","no-reset","no-run","printErrors"]
 #Note: my long_options are considered boolean 
 #so if it exists in arg it is considered as True or False

toptions = "" #ignoring short codes in this,as the question is for long options
long_options =["help","no-reset","no-run","printErrors"] #as for thequestion["symbol=","vendor="]  
 #creating list variables to store values  
unrecognisedlist = []
recognised = []
 # looping over sys arg, I will explain it below
for arg in sys.argv[1:] :recognised.append(arg) if arg.strip('--') in long_options else unrecognisedlist.append(arg)

#best practice: show there are unrecognised options to the user
#<any error handling code for unrecognised>
print("these options are unrecognised",unrecognisedlist)
try:
    # Parsing only recognized arguments
    arguments, values = getopt.getopt(recognised, toptions, long_options)`

           #<your codes with arguments and values>
           #Such as,
    for currentArgument, currentValue in arguments:
        print("checking for arguments") 
     #including short options for reference  
        if currentArgument in ("-h", "--help"):
            print ("Displaying Help")
            print(" -n , --no-reset : will not reset last session of the app , useful to skip certain login scenarios")
            print ('"-r", "--no-run"',"testcases will not execute only evaluate")                no_run = True

        elif currentArgument in ("-n", "--no-reset"):
            print ("no reset turned on. App will not reset in each execution")
            noreset = True
         
        elif currentArgument in ("-r", "--no-run"):

            print (("testcases will not execute with no run option :: (% s) ::") % (currentValue))
            no_run = True

        elif currentArgument in ("-e","--printErrors"):
            print("opening file changes.txt , system will exit after print")
            print("text case run disabled")
            no_run = True
            with open('changes.txt') as file_object:
                for line in file_object:
                    print(line,"", end='')
            sys.exit("\n\nCHANGES AND ERRORS are printed IN changes.txt now exiting\n\n")

except Exceptions as e:
     print(e)
```

**Now I will break down the iteration logic for you,**

***#the one liner***

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:] :recognised.append(arg) if arg.strip('--') in long_options else unrecognisedlist.append(arg)
```

**is same as**

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:] :
    recognised.append(arg) if arg.strip('--') in long_options else unrecognisedlist.append(arg)
```

**or more elaborately**

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:] :
    if arg.strip('--') in long_options:
         recognised.append(arg)
    else:
         unrecognisedlist.append(arg)
```

since we get all the passed arguments in "**sys.argv[1:]** ", we will iterate over each and append it to the appropriate list variables.

we need to strip the arg with **arg.strip('--')** because the sys.argv[1:] returns those with "--" prefixed string exactly like we are passing it through options,
Then we check each with that in long_option , if a match found -append it to recognised and else unrecognisedlist

Comment: Hi, this does solve the error, but since those options are not related with my code at all,  my wish is what if I don't want specificly write code to ignore such "--" options.

Comment: you can just leave the long_options blank for that 
like,
`long_options = []`

Comment: I doubt this might be the only solution for now, thanks Jihad